# Is it possible to add physics to geometry nodes?

Tags: physics, geometry-nodes

I'm instantiating lots of objects with geometry nodes and now I want to add rigid body physics to those objects so that I can make an animation of them falling. Is it possible to do this?

I don't want to apply the geometry nodes modifier and then simulate just one configuration of this setup. I want to be able to change the geometry nodes parameters on the fly and then simulate them.

I'm using Blender `3.3.1`.

Comment: without applying...up to now...no.

Comment: You can add cloth physics, but not rigid body.

Comment: Too bad, it would be really neat to have this type of thing so that I don't have to apply every time I want to see my objects in action :/